# Dead Space 3 won't detect Mass Effect 3 save

Tags: dead-space-3

So me and my friend want to replay DE3. In the game if you have a ME3 save on your pc it will unlock the N7 suit. Since i don't have ME3 i asked my buddy to send me one of his characters save folder. For some reason it wont detect the save. Any idea whats the problem? Do i have to do something else?

Comment: You want a reward for playing a game that you haven't actually played?

Comment: Obvious explaination is that the save file isn't located in the location that DS is looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

Game save may be tied to one Origin account or Mass Effect 3 has to be in your Origin library - in that case you have no other option than purchase the game.